# Typescript - forward and useref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two components:

```
const ComponentOne = () => {
   const a = React.useRef<ComponentTwo>(null);
                // ^^^^^^^^^^ throws error - ComponentTwo refers to a value but used as type here
   const fn = () => {
      a.current.open(); // how to type it so typescript knows than open() is a function

      a.current.awdokawd(); // typescript should throw error here
   };

   return (
      <ComponentTwo ref={a} />
   );
}

const ComponentTwo = React.forwardRef((props, ref: React.RefObject<What here?>) => {
                                                            // ^^^^ what to type here?
   React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      open: () => {
         console.log('hey');
      },
   }));

   return (
      ...
   );
});
```

So as you can see, Im not sure what to enter with `useRef` so typescript properly recognizes the component and its method. Also not sure what to type with `forwardRef`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing the ref down to a DOM component? if so, the type in both instances is the type of that element, I think.  But seeing as you are calling methods on your ref object, I'm not convinced ref forwarding is really what you want here.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I want to call children method from parent.

Comment: A function component (which ComponentTwo is) doesn't have methods.  It takes props and returns some JSX/HTML code.  So this doesn't make sense.   A better design is for ComponentOne to own the method and state and pass it down to ComponentTwo.

Comment: You're able to inject that method with`useImperativeHandle`, but the description of that hook is basically "don't use this": `useImperativeHandle customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using ref. As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases.`

Comment: @LindaPaiste That's not true, the `useImperativeHandle` hook aims to mimic the behaviour of class methods when using ref. This is a totally valid pattern, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Comment: @LindaPaiste My friend Im totally aware that it should be rather avoided but I really need to use it. Thats the 0,01% of cases that it needs to be done this way.

Comment: Fair enough. It's definitely not an ideal design but yes it is technically possible.  @Yanick's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to declare a new type for the ref:

```js
interface ComponentTwoRef {
    open(): void;
}

const ComponentOne = () => {
   const a = React.useRef<ComponentTwoRef>(null);

   const fn = () => {
      a.current.open();

      a.current.awdokawd(); // typescript should throw error here
   };

   return (
      <ComponentTwo ref={a} />
   );
}

const ComponentTwo = React.forwardRef((props, ref: React.RefObject<ComponentTwoRef>) => {

   React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      open: () => {
         console.log('hey');
      },
   }));

   return (
      ...
   );
});
```

Comment: Isnt there any other way to do it? This looks pretty easy but lil bit naive also... and hardcoded.

Comment: I mean, unless you want to go with a class component, there is not. That's precisely what TS is for, you sometimes have to define stuff.

Comment: I would say it's the name `ComponentTwoRef` that makes it feel hardcoded.  If you change the name to `Openable`, where it is an interface describing any object with a void `open()` method, then it feels more natural. `useRef<Openable>` implies "I need a ref to something that I can open."

Comment: Yeah that's another option, never thought of it this way!